# Was the Parochet in the Kodesh ha-Kodashim ever cleaned/replaced?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, yom-kippur, kohen-gadol

[Mishnah Yoma 5:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Yoma.5.4?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) describes how the Kohen Gadol sprinkles blood on the Parochet in the Kodesh ha-Kodashim (he does this twice, with different bloods):

> נָטַל דַּם הַפָּר וְהִנִּיחַ דַּם הַשָּׂעִיר, וְהִזָּה מִמֶּנּוּ עַל
> הַפָּרֹכֶת שֶׁכְּנֶגֶד הָאָרוֹן מִבַּחוּץ

We know that he will re-enter the Kodesh ha-Kodashim to remove the Ketoret materials. But given that only the Kohen Gadol can enter there (and only once a year), does he ever clean the Parochet and the rest of the interior? Does the Parochet ever get replaced? It seems like it would become putrid - unless it's miraculously cleansed like the Lashon shel Zehorit (the red wool that turns white after the goat of Azazel goes over the cliff)?

I'm aware of [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67956/cleaning-blood-from-the-temple) and the others that link to it, but the assumption there seems to be that the blood doesn't get on the Parochet.

Comment: Hi, I believe I saw a gemara that talks about how it was cleaned. I could be wrong, if I find it I'll send an answer

Comment: Tamid 29b @RabbiKaii

Comment: Actually one answer quotes the Gemara that Reb Yosi saw it in Rome and it had blood stains, so it wasn’t cleaned.  https://www.sefaria.org/Meilah.17b.7?lang=bi

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud in [Tamid (29B)](https://www.sefaria.org/Tamid.29b.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) says they made two new curtains every year (There were [two curtains separating the kodesh from the kodesh hakodosim](https://www.sefaria.org/Tamid.29b.3?lang=bi&p2=Mefaresh_on_Tamid.29b.3.3&lang2=bi&lookup2=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9F&w2=Lexicon&lang3=en#:%7E:text=%D7%91%27%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%93-,%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9F,-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%9C%D7%90)). It also says it was immersed in a mikvah, the commentaries seem split on whether that was before it was put into use, or if it became impure while it was in use.

Note that immersing it doesn't necessarily mean they cleaned it well.

Comment: It's quoting mishna Shekalim 8:5.